# Receiving a Fatal Error on multiple file upload

Tags: php, mysql, image, file, upload

I have made a script to upload multiple files using a form:

```
<form action="upload_image.php" id="form_img" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div align="center">
        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
            <span>Carica immagini nella galleria</span>
            <input type="file" name="immagini[]" multiple="multiple" id="file_img" class="upload"/>
            <script>
            document.getElementById("file_img").onchange = function() {
                document.getElementById("form_img").submit();
            };
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The javascript code is supposed to submit the form when user have chosen a file and here is the php I am using to process the upload:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
$where = dirname(__FILE__);
include($where . "/config/db.php");
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

foreach ($_FILES as $file) {   
    $nome_file_temporaneo = $file["tmp_name"];
    $nome_file_vero = $file["name"];
    $tipo_file = $file["type"];
    $not_profilo = '1';

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($tipo_file);$i++) {
        $dati_file = file_get_contents($nome_file_temporaneo[$i]);
        $query = "INSERT INTO ".$_SESSION['id']." (immagine,type,profilo) values (?,?,?)";

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $dati_file, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $tipo_file[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $not_profilo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
header("location: profile_set.php");
?>
```

This gives me an error:

> Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\tp\upload_image.php on line 24

*Line 24 is the line that contains: `$stmt->execute()`*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If i had a penny for every time I urged people to avoid storing files in their databases, I could takeover oracle. So one more time. Don't save file contents in the database.

Comment: What is the rest of the fatal error say? Fatal error what?

Answer (score 0):

Try binding using an array inserted into the `->execute(array())`. If you want to make sure that values are what they should be, just do some validation in the `foreach()` loop. One last thing, you say your form does multiple uploading but you have only one input and you have it upload as soon as the input changes, so that is a tad confusing:

```
// I am just saving your connection to a function just to clean it up a bit
function connection()
    {
        include(__DIR__."/config/db.php");
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $dbh;
    }
// I like to reogranize my $_FILES array so each file is in it's own array
function organize($array = false)
    {
        if(!is_array($array) || empty($array))
            return $array;

        foreach($array['name'] as $key => $value) {

                if($array['error'][$key] != 0) {
                        $files[$key]    =   false;
                        continue;
                    }

                $files[$key]    =   array(
                                            "name"      =>  $array['name'][$key],
                                            "tmp_name"  =>  $array['tmp_name'][$key],
                                            "type"      =>  $array['type'][$key],
                                            "error"     =>  $array['error'][$key],
                                            "size"      =>  $array['size'][$key]
                                        );
            }

        return $files;
    }

// This will return an array of bind values and statement values
function CompileUpload($use_name = 'immagini')
    {
        // If empty, do nothing
        if(empty($_FILES[$use_name]))
            return false;

        //Reorganize array
        $FILES  =   organize($_FILES[$use_name]);
        $return =   false;
        foreach ($FILES as $i => $file) { 
            if($file["error"] !== 0)
                continue;
            // I would suggest just saving the name and location of
            // the file(s) instead of saving them to the database. 
            $temp = $file["tmp_name"];
            $name = $file["name"];
            $type = $file["type"];
            $data = file_get_contents($temp);
            // Create a bind array
            $bind[":".$i."name"]    =   $name;
            $bind[":".$i."type"]    =   $type;
            $bind[":".$i."data"]    =   $data;
            // Create the append values for the sql statement
            $bCols[$i][]    =   ":".$i."name";
            $bCols[$i][]    =   ":".$i."type";
            $bCols[$i][]    =   ":".$i."data";
            // Implode and save to a master row array
            $iCols[]        =   "(".implode(",",$bCols[$i]).")";
        }
        // If there is no bind array (errors in file array)
        // just return false
        if(empty($bind))
            return false;
        // assign bind
        $return['bind'] =   $bind;
        // Implode rows
        $return['cols'] =   implode(",",$iCols);
        // return the final data array
        return $return;
    }
```

**To use:**

```
    // Make sure to include the above functions here....

    // Get the uploads
    $uploads    =   CompileUpload();
    // If there are uploads and the user is logged in
    if(!empty($uploads) && !empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
            // Is this really correct? Do you have a table for each user?
            // Compile your statement
            $statement  =   "INSERT into `".$_SESSION['id']."` (`immagine`,`type`,`profilo`) VALUES ".$uploads['cols'];
            // Get connection and prepare
            // You may need to do $con = connection(); $con->prepare...etc.
            // but this should work
            $query      =   connection()->prepare($statement);
            // Execute with bind values
            $query->execute($uploads['bind']);
        }
```

The sql statement would look something like this:

```
INSERT into `whatever` (`immagine`,`type`,`profilo`) VALUES (:0name,:0type,:0data)
```

Multiple uploads would be:

```
INSERT into `whatever` (`immagine`,`type`,`profilo`) VALUES (:0name,:0type,:0data),(:1name,:1type,:1data)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Resclatt, code work, in part.. now the problem is that i haven't got any error in the upload_image.php page, and all the files sent to db have only 1B of size..

Comment: Do `print_r($uploads);` to see if it's populated properly with the upload data

Comment: Sorry, it was a problem of mine code,not yours... i was storing 'profilo' as 'immagine' column, so it were insert only '1' in the blob column.

Comment: Sounds good. Make sure to mark the question answered if it worked.